# Python: take screenshot from video

Tags: python, video, screenshot, video-processing

The idea is that, user should be able to load a video from their local machine and tell the program to take a screenshot from the video every 5sec or 30sec. Is there any library to help me with this task? Any idea from how to proceed would be helpful.

Comment: ```opencv``` - you can ```video_capture``` the video, and then process it frame by frame (say - saving the one you want to get "screen shooted")

Answer (score 7):

install opencv-python (which is an unofficial pre-built OpenCV package for Python) by issuing the following command:

> ```
> pip install opencv-python
> ```

```
# Importing all necessary libraries
import cv2
import os
import time

# Read the video from specified path
cam = cv2.VideoCapture("C:/Users/User/Desktop/videoplayback.mp4")

try:

    # creating a folder named data
    if not os.path.exists('data'):
        os.makedirs('data')

    # if not created then raise error
except OSError:
    print('Error: Creating directory of data')

# frame
currentframe = 0

while (True):
    time.sleep(5) # take schreenshot every 5 seconds
    # reading from frame
    ret, frame = cam.read()

    if ret:
        # if video is still left continue creating images
        name = './data/frame' + str(currentframe) + '.jpg'
        print('Creating...' + name)

        # writing the extracted images
        cv2.imwrite(name, frame)

        # increasing counter so that it will
        # show how many frames are created
        currentframe += 1
    else:
        break

# Release all space and windows once done
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is it also possible to define to take screenshots lets say at 30th second of the video, 40th second and 55th second of the video?

Comment: The time.sleep(5) part only makes the script work slower not for the screenshot interval

Answer (score 5):

the above answer is partially right but time.sleep here does not help at all but rather it makes the process slower. however, if you want to take a screenshot at a certain time of a video you need to understand that every time you do "ret, frame = cam.read()" it reads the next frame of the video. every second in a video has a number of frames depends on the video. you get that number using:

```
  frame_per_second = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
```

so if you need to take a screenshot of the 3rd second you can keep the iteration as is in the above answer and just add

```
  if currentframe == (3*frame_per_second):  
      cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
```

this will take a screenshot of the first frame in the 3rd second.

Comment: I believe your condition is actually incorrect. It should be something like: `if currentframe % (frame_per_second*3) == 0:`

Answer (score 2):

```
#ncica & Data_sniffer solution remake
import cv2
import os
import time

step = 10
frames_count = 3
cam = cv2.VideoCapture('video/example.MP4')

currentframe = 0
frame_per_second = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) 
frames_captured = 0

while (True):
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if ret:
        if currentframe > (step*frame_per_second):  
            currentframe = 0
            name = 'photo/frame' + str(frames_captured) + '.jpg'
            print(name)
            cv2.imwrite(name, frame)            
            frames_captured+=1
            if frames_captured>frames_count-1:
                ret = False
        currentframe += 1           
    if ret==False:
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#a generic function incorporating all the comments mentioned above.

def get_frames(inputFile,outputFolder,step,count):

  '''
  Input:
    inputFile - name of the input file with directoy
    outputFolder - name and path of the folder to save the results
    step - time lapse between each step (in seconds)
    count - number of screenshots
  Output:
    'count' number of screenshots that are 'step' seconds apart created from video 'inputFile' and stored in folder 'outputFolder'
  Function Call:
    get_frames("test.mp4", 'data', 10, 10)
  '''

  #initializing local variables
  step = step
  frames_count = count

  currentframe = 0
  frames_captured = 0

  #creating a folder
  try:  
      # creating a folder named data 
      if not os.path.exists(outputFolder): 
          os.makedirs(outputFolder) 
    
  #if not created then raise error 
  except OSError: 
      print ('Error! Could not create a directory') 
  
  #reading the video from specified path 
  cam = cv2.VideoCapture(inputFile) 

  #reading the number of frames at that particular second
  frame_per_second = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

  while (True):
      ret, frame = cam.read()
      if ret:
          if currentframe > (step*frame_per_second):  
              currentframe = 0
              #saving the frames (screenshots)
              name = './data/frame' + str(frames_captured) + '.jpg'
              print ('Creating...' + name) 
              
              cv2.imwrite(name, frame)       
              frames_captured+=1
              
              #breaking the loop when count achieved
              if frames_captured > frames_count-1:
                ret = False
          currentframe += 1           
      if ret == False:
          break
  
  #Releasing all space and windows once done
  cam.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions provided do not work for me in several cases.

The FPS from `cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS` is a floating point value and the FPS rate of my `testvid.mp4` was `23.976023976023978` according to this property.

When looping through `current_frame / fps % 3`, we will almost always have leftovers because of this floating point value. Same goes for `(3*frame_per_second):`, causing our `imwrite` to never be reached.

I solved this issue by using the same calculations, but storing the remainders and comparing those:

```py
    current_frame = 0
    fps_calculator_previous = 0
    while (True):
        ret, frame = cam.read()

        if ret:
            # Still got video left.
            file_name = f"./data_generation/out/{_fn}-{current_frame}.jpg"


            fps_calculator = (current_frame / fps) % every_x_sec
            if(fps_calculator - fps_calculator_previous < 0):
                print("Found a frame to write!")
                cv2.imwrite(file_name, frame)
            fps_calculator_previous = fps_calculator

            current_frame += 1
        else:
            break
```

This seems to work well for me with any value for both `cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS` as well as `every_x_sec`

My video was 18 minutes and 7 seconds long, and I captured 362 unique frames from that with `every_x_sec` set to 3.

Answer (score 1):

Edited @ncica's code and noted that it is working fine.

```
import cv2
import os
import time

cam = cv2.VideoCapture("/path/to/videoIn.mp4")

try:
    if not os.path.exists('data'):
        os.makedirs('data')

except OSError:
    print('Error: Creating directory of data')

intvl = 2 #interval in second(s)

fps= int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
print("fps : " ,fps)

currentframe = 0
while (True):
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if ret:
        if(currentframe % (fps*intvl) == 0):
            name = './data/frame' + str(currentframe) + '.jpg'
            print('Creating...' + name)
            cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
        currentframe += 1
    else:
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The trick is it is looping frame-by-frame.
So, here we are capturing frames that we want and write disk as snapshot image file.
eg : If you want snapshot two second by two second `intvl` must be 2

Answer (score 0):

To add on data_sniffer's answer. I would recommend using round (Math function) on frame_per_second when checking as if the frame rate is a decimal number then it will go into an infinite loop.

Comment: Hi, if this isn't a direct answer to the question, it's better to say it as a comment. Instead of a new answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reps to do that but I still wanted to put it out there.